# twenty twelve widgets weird display in internet explorer 8

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer, cross-browser

In IE8, I set up a three widget areas, but it displays vertically instead of horizontally. It works fine in IE9 and all the other browsers. I put the same css in the `ie.css` conditional of the twenty twelve child theme.

Here's the [link](http://www.cavagnagroup.com/) and my css:

ie.css

```
/*
Styles for older IE versions (previous to IE9).
*/

body {
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
}
body.custom-background-empty {
    background-color: #fff;
}
body.custom-background-empty .site,
body.custom-background-white .site {
    box-shadow: none;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.assistive-text,
.site .screen-reader-text {
    clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE7 */
}
.full-width .site-content {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
}
img.size-full,
img.size-large,
img.header-image,
img.wp-post-image,
img[class*="align"],
img[class*="wp-image-"],
img[class*="attachment-"] {
    width: auto; /* Prevent stretching of full-size and large-size images with height and width attributes in IE8 */
}
.author-avatar {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-top: 0.571428571rem;
}
.author-description {
    float: right;
    width: 80%;
}
.site {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.3);
    margin: 48px auto;
    max-width: 960px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0 40px;
}
.site-content {
    float: left;
    width: 65.104166667%;
}
body.template-front-page .site-content,
body.attachment .site-content,
body.full-width .site-content {
    width: 100%;
}
/*.widget-area {
    float: right;
    width: 26.041666667%;
}*/
.site-header h1,
.site-header h2 {
    text-align: left;
}
.site-header h1 {
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 1.846153846;
}
.main-navigation ul.nav-menu,
.main-navigation div.nav-menu > ul {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;
    border-top: 1px solid #ededed;
    display: inline-block !important;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.main-navigation ul {
    margin: 0;
    text-indent: 0;
}
.main-navigation li a,
.main-navigation li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.ie7 .main-navigation li a,
.ie7 .main-navigation li {
    display: inline;
}
.main-navigation li a {
    border-bottom: 0;
    color: #6a6a6a;
    line-height: 3.692307692;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.main-navigation li a:hover {
    color: #000;
}
.main-navigation li {
    margin: 0 40px 0 0;
    position: relative;
}
.main-navigation li ul {
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}
.ie7 .main-navigation li ul {
    left: 0;
}
.main-navigation li ul ul,
.ie7 .main-navigation li ul ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
}
.main-navigation ul li:hover > ul {
    border-left: 0;
    display: block;
}
.main-navigation li ul li a {
    background: #efefef;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;
    display: block;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 2.181818182;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    width: 180px;
}
.main-navigation li ul li a:hover {
    background: #e3e3e3;
    color: #444;
}
.main-navigation .current-menu-item > a,
.main-navigation .current-menu-ancestor > a,
.main-navigation .current_page_item > a,
.main-navigation .current_page_ancestor > a {
    color: #636363;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.menu-toggle {
    display: none;
}
.entry-header .entry-title {
    font-size: 22px;
}
#respond form input[type="text"] {
    width: 46.333333333%;
}
#respond form textarea.blog-textarea {
    width: 79.666666667%;
}
.template-front-page .site-content,
.template-front-page article {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.template-front-page.has-post-thumbnail article {
    float: left;
    width: 47.916666667%;
}
.entry-page-image {
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    width: 47.916666667%;
}
/*.template-front-page .widget-area .widget,
.template-front-page.two-sidebars .widget-area .front-widgets {
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    width: 51.875%;
}
.template-front-page .widget-area .widget:nth-child(odd) {
    clear: right;
}
.template-front-page .widget-area .widget:nth-child(even),
.template-front-page.two-sidebars .widget-area .front-widgets + .front-widgets {
    float: right;
    margin: 0 0 24px;
    width: 39.0625%;
}
.template-front-page.two-sidebars .widget,
.template-front-page.two-sidebars .widget:nth-child(even) {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
}*/

/* =RTL overrides for IE7 and IE8
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
.rtl .site-header h1,
.rtl .site-header h2 {
    text-align: right;
}
.rtl .widget-area,
.rtl .author-description {
    float: left;
}
.rtl .author-avatar,
.rtl .site-content {
    float: right;
}
.rtl .main-navigation ul.nav-menu,
.rtl .main-navigation div.nav-menu > ul {
    text-align: right;
}
.rtl .main-navigation ul li ul li,
.rtl .main-navigation ul li ul li ul li {
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.rtl .main-navigation li ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}
.ie7 .rtl .main-navigation li ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}
.ie7 .rtl .main-navigation ul li {
    z-index: 99;
}
.ie7 .rtl .main-navigation li ul {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}
.ie7 .rtl .main-navigation li {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: 40px;
}
.ie7 .rtl .main-navigation li ul ul ul {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}

.template-front-page.two-sidebars .widget-area .front-widgets, 
    .template-front-page .widget-area .widget:nth-child(even),
    .template-front-page.two-sidebars .widget-area .front-widgets + .front-widgets {
        float: left !important;
        width: 30.3% !important;
        margin-left: 1.5% !important;
        margin-right: 1.5% !important;
        min-height:200px !important;
        _height: 200px;
    }
    .template-front-page .widget-area .widget:nth-child(odd) {
        clear: none !important;
    }
    .template-front-page .widget-area .widget:nth-child(3n+3) {
        clear: right!important;  
    }
```

Comment: Why is all the ccs for the widgets commented? It seems you're missing a float:left; for the bottom 3 widgets?

Comment: i commented that css because it was worst! i was seeing the widgets like 50 px wide

Comment: the css that rules the widgets is in the final part of the css, beginning with

Comment: try to add a float left for the widget elements!